# Perfect copy of Yun with Micro SD

Tags: arduino-yun, sd-card

My Yun has a micro SD card with shared file system using [ExpandingYunDiskSpace](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ExpandingYunDiskSpace).

I would like to copy my Yun/SD card data **perfectly** onto my backup Yun/SD card. Because I have made many changes to the filesystem, just re-running the whole process manually would take a long time.

What methods can I use to transfer my Yun's data onto my other Yun?

My other Yun is brand new (never plugged in), and I have a brand new SD card in there. If I can do a 'bit-perfect' transfer for Yun and Micro SD in one shot that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying an SD card (cloning) is easy enough to do.  On Windows you can use [Win32DiskImager](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/win32diskimager).  On Linux and OS X you can either use `dd` from the command line:

```
(read)
$ dd if=/dev/sdb of=MySD.img bs=32k

(write)
$ dd id=MySD.img of=/dev/sdb bs=32k
```

For OS X the device names will be different, also in Linux you need to check which /dev/sd?? it is.

Also in Linux and OS X there are GUI applications that can do it for you - the Disk Manager in OS X, and "Gnome Disks" in Linux.

That is only good for the actual SD card contents though.  If you need to clone the actual Yún itself then it becomes more tricky.

Fortunately there are tools available to help you.

Details on how to create and restore a backup of an OpenWRT system (which is what the Yún is) can be found on the OpenWRT Wiki: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.backup

Note that again it requires a Linux or OS X (preferably the former) system to do it since it relies on the standard Unix scripting tools and commands that are lacking on a Windows system.

You may be able to do all the above on a Windows system if you make it look like a Linux system by installing Cygwin.